# Provide special character password in RTSP stream

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, rtsp

I'm using vlc to read rtsp stream like this:

```
rtsp://username:password@!@192.168.1.108:15667/cam/realmonitor?channel=30&subtype=0
```

with username is "username" and password is "password@!"

VLC seems to be unable to read the link correctly when I check the [messages](https://justpaste.it/9nnw4). My VLC version is 3.0.8.
Is there a way to make VLC read the provided stream probably?

Comment: share full logs

Comment: @mfkl the logs above is the full logs. Am I missing something ?

Comment: try removing the '@' from the password to see if that's the cause of the problem, try vlc latest 3.0.11

Answer (score 11):

Special characters in url must be escaped, the way of doing it is by encoding the characters into url encoding.

Specifically in this caseyou need to replace `@` with `%40` and `!` with `%21`
You can find the encoding of all the relevant characters here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution  is not working for me.